# RSS pubDate parsing with ROME

Tags: java, rss, rome

I wanted to give ROME a try to parse some feeds, when suddenly it was unable to parse some `pubDate` fields formatted as `<pubDate>2013-08-30 20:23:00</pubDate>` with a `null` result, but it was ok to format that type of fields `<pubDate>Fri, 30 Aug 2013 17:42:04 +0300</pubDate>`.

So what's the trick? it is possible somehow to get the result even if there is not a format supported by ROME? or maybe there are some another good RSS parsers comparing to ROME?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced issues with the pubDate field. However the format of Thu, 30 Mar 2017 08:00:57 +0100 yields null. (Rss version 0.91)

However bumping the version to 0.93 solved the issue. This is also according to the specs version 0.91 (and 0.92) that do not have a pubDate at item level, only at feed level.